# How to present a login workflow? (modal and navigationController)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I currently need to present a login screen, followed by other screens before returning to the main menu.

Currently, I check if anyone is logged in on the main menu, and then present a modal login view (inside a UINavigationController) if not.
The user then fills in their login details and clicks submit. But before returning to the main menu (now logged in), I need to present two more screens to display some options.

I am not sure which structure to use for this. I thought about pushing the options screen onto the stack when the use clicks the submit button. However, Once they are done with that screen, and pop back to the root (login) view controller, is there any way to dismiss the modal view automatically, or should I structure this in another way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can push your login screen within a UINavigationController and use this controller to push your additional, post login screens.

```
// create and add your view controller to a navigation Controller
LoginController *loginController = [[LoginController alloc] init]; 
UINavigationController *navigationController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootController:loginController];
// present it modally
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Once your user are done with the last of the post login screens, calling dismissViewController on the navigationController will go back to your main screens.

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: But how do I call the protocol method if it is in the first screen presented (login)?
The main menu presents the login and is the logins' delegate. So how do I make it so that I can dismiss from the 3rd screen?

Comment: if you call dismissViewController on the navigationController (which has been presented modally from your main menu) it will dismiss the whole stack and return to your main menu

Comment: and this can be call on any view controller (login screen or your additional screens)

Comment: But the navigation controller isn't supposed to call dismiss, the screen which presents the modal (the main menu) calls dismiss right?

Comment: when you call dismissViewController on a viewController presented modally (through presentViewController: animated:) it will dismissed itself and return to the presenting View Controller.

Comment: When I call it from the 2nd or 3rd view controller inside the navigation controller, it gets rid of the controller, but leaves the 'page' effect at the top (partial curl effect), leaving me to believe that it has not dismissed properly

Comment: Could you paste the code you use to present and dismiss your controllers please

Comment: Eric - found the problem with my code, was applying the modal transition style to the login view rather than the navigation view, causing the effect to stay.
Your solution now works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so is to present it modally in your app delegate where you are using the navigation controller, just initialise your login view here and present it modally from your navigation controller like follows.

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:loginView animated:yes];

and inside your loginview just use

[self.navigationController dismissViewController animated:YES];

Comment: But I am pushing other views on top of the login view. Therefore when I call dismiss from the other views, it is not dismissing properly

Comment: you need to dismiss it for the viewController your currently in, like  A pushed B now your in B, Now from here being in B you can dismiss.
where A and B a view controllers, A presented B Modally, and when you are in B you can dismiss it to get back to A.

If you need something else Please detail your query.